# My Ubuntu is not starting anymore, end on on BusyBox / initramfs

Tags: boot, 18.04, initramfs, busybox

I'm using Ubuntu Desktop 18.04.4. I was having a conference call on [jitsi.org](https://jitsi.org/) (a great Free software for VOIP) and I wanted to share my screen with my guest. It is at that point that my computer froze, though I could still talk to my guest. As I couldn't control the computer anymore, I turned the computer off.

Then I powered it on, and this is where I realized that Ubuntu wasn't booting anymore. Instead, I am ending up on BusyBox/initramfs.

My hard disks are encrypted, so I don't know if that's the reason, but when I look through `/dev/`, I cannot see any `sda` or `sdb` disks.

[image: Here is the proof that sda or sdb are not listed]

I booted with a live USB key and same thing: I cannot access my hard drives from there.

The messages I am getting are:

```
WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Failing back to device scanning. And it goes into loop.
Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found.
Cannot process group "ubuntu-vg".
```

[image: WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad.]

I am desperate here. Does anyone has any solution to this? Is my hard drive dead?

Here is what turns out the following command, as you can see the 500Gb hard disk is not showing:

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disque /dev/loop0 : 1,93 GiB, 2049204224 octets, 4002352 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop1 : 27,9 MiB, 28405760 octets, 55480 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop2 : 54,97 MiB, 57614336 octets, 112528 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop3 : 240,82 MiB, 252493824 octets, 493152 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop4 : 62,9 MiB, 65105920 octets, 127160 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/loop5 : 49,8 MiB, 52203520 octets, 101960 secteurs
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets


Disque /dev/sdb : 3,83 GiB, 4089446400 octets, 7987200 secteurs
Disk model: Flash Disk      
Unités : secteur de 1 × 512 = 512 octets
Taille de secteur (logique / physique) : 512 octets / 512 octets
taille d'E/S (minimale / optimale) : 512 octets / 512 octets
Type d'étiquette de disque : dos
Identifiant de disque : 0x15f006ae

Périphérique Amorçage   Début     Fin Secteurs Taille Id Type
/dev/sdb1    *              0 5303231  5303232   2,5G  0 Vide
/dev/sdb2             4222640 4230575     7936   3,9M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)
/dev/sdb3             5304320 7987199  2682880   1,3G 83 Linux
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine https://twitter.com/CyrilBrulebois solved it for me.
Here is what he advised me to:
1) use a live ubuntu usb key
2) once ubuntu loaded just go to the terminal, then enter dmesg command.
3) he reads the lines and one was saying that one device has been found and the mode was changed from AHCI to RAID and here was the thing.
4) I went on the BIOS and changed the Sata configuration to Raid to AHCI then everything goes back to normal.
I was ready to purchase a new hard disk, now I am happier than ever.
Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

do you have a raid??
Looks like a broken controller to me. Encrypted or not, you should be able to see sda and sdb, unless they are hidden by a raid controller.

Comment: I ran cat /proc/mdstat from an Ubuntu live usb key and it answeers: Personalities: unused devices: <none> so I guess no Raid are installed. Am I right?